# Malmoe: section in footer

Tags: beamer

I currently have this in my preamble:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
% add page numbers for malmoe    
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
```

This gives me a very simple style that has

> Author - Title - Pagenumber

in the footer. For my next presentation, I would like to change this to

> Author - Current Section - Pagenumber

I guess reusing the older trick of `\renewcommand\title` would replace the title also in the front slide.  What's the correct approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current section name is saved in the macro `\secname`.  If just want that printed then it is enough to replate `\oldmacro` by `\secname` in your redefinition of `\insertshorttitle`.  If you also want a link to the start of the section, then that may be done as follows:

```
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \hyperlinksectionstart{\secname}\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
```

since `\hyperlinksectionstart` builds a link to the start of the current section.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \hyperlinksectionstart{\secname}\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\begin{document}

\title{My presentation}
\author{Myself}

\section{First section}

\begin{frame}{Frame}
  Test
\end{frame}

\section{Second section}

\begin{frame}{Frame}
  Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the `split` outer theme (used in Malmoe) is not right for you. I suggest using the `boxes` outer theme instead:

```
\usetheme{boxes}
\usecolortheme{whale} % Used in Malmoe
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{parent=structure} % Used in Malmoe

\addfootbox{author in head/foot}{\hfill\insertshortauthor\tiny\quad}

\addfootbox{title in head/foot}{%
    \tiny\quad\insertsection%
    \hfill%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}{%
        \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber%
    }\tiny\quad}

\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=white}
```

I used the `whale` color theme, with modified `titlelike` color, [as is done in Malmoe](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/theme/beamerthemeMalmoe.sty).
The `boxes` theme allows you to easily add boxes to the header and footer, as you can see.

The first parameter of `\addfootbox` is the color you want the box to be, and the second one is the content of the box.